# "Image Animator 3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I'm writing a Java program and recently I added a .GIF image into it. Here is the code:

```
package rtype;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Alien extends RType {

private Image aliens;
private int x;
private int y;
private boolean visible;
private String type;
private ImageIcon ii;

public Alien(String type) {

    this.type = type;

    if ("Normal".equals(type)) {
        ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("alien_normal.gif"));
    } else if ("Rapid".equals(type)) {

//before adding this line all things are OK!


        ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("alien_rapid.gif"));   
    }

    aliens = ii.getImage();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    x = rnd.nextInt(328) + 15;
    y = 0;
    visible = true;

}

public void move() {

    if ("Normal".equals(this.type)) {
        y += 1;
    } else if ("Rapid".equals(this.type)) {
        y += 2;
    }

    if (y > 530) {
        visible = false;
    }
}

public Image getImage() {
    return aliens;
}


@Override
public int getX() {
    return x;
}

@Override
public int getY() {
    return y;
}

@Override
public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

@Override
public void setVisible(boolean i) {
    visible = i;
}

}
```

But now the following error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "Image Animator 3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.awt.image.IndexColorModel.<init>(IndexColorModel.java:338)
at sun.awt.image.GifImageDecoder.readImage(GifImageDecoder.java:526)
at sun.awt.image.GifImageDecoder.produceImage(GifImageDecoder.java:212)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:269)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
```

I think It should be noted that I Recoloured the **alien_normal.gif** with an Online tool to produce my **alien_rapid.gif**.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which is the 338 line?

Comment: This is just the model / bean class, where is the main metod

Comment: here is the main method, But the problem is in that class itself .
package rtype;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RType extends JFrame {
        
    public RType() {
        
        add(new Board());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("STAR WARS");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RType rType = new RType();
    }
}

Comment: And how big is your recoloured gif?

Comment: The point is that, the recolored image is not big, but has the same size as the original one!